# Elasticsearch partitioned indices skipped versus match no docs query

Tags: elasticsearch

We're having indices that are partitioned by year, e.g.:

```
items-2019
items-2020
```

Consider the following data:

```json
POST items-2019/_doc
{
  "@timestamp": "2019-01-01"
}

POST items-2020/_doc
{
  "@timestamp": "2020-01-01"
}


POST /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "items-*",
        "alias": "items"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when I query data and explicitly sort results, it would skip `items-2020` shards:

```json
GET items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "lt": "2020-01-01"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "@timestamp": "desc"
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 1,    <--- skipped
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "items-2019",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "BTdSb3UBRFH0Yqe1vm_W",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2019-01-01"
        },
        "sort" : [
          1546300800000
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However when I don't sort results explicitly, it wouldn't skip the shards, however ES would issue a MatchNoDocsQuery:

```json
GET items/_search
{
  "profile": "true",
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "lt": "2020-01-01"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,    <--- nothing skipped
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "items-2019",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "BTdSb3UBRFH0Yqe1vm_W",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2019-01-01"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "profile" : {
    "shards" : [
      {
        "id" : "[Axyv60mYQEGAREa2TwbgMQ][items-2019][0]",
        "searches" : [
          {
            "query" : [
              {
                "type" : "ConstantScoreQuery",
                "description" : "ConstantScore(DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=@timestamp])",
                "time_in_nanos" : 69525,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                  "match_count" : 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                  "next_doc" : 3766,
                  "match" : 0,
                  "next_doc_count" : 1,
                  "score_count" : 1,
                  "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                  "compute_max_score" : 0,
                  "advance" : 4123,
                  "advance_count" : 1,
                  "score" : 1123,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 2,
                  "create_weight" : 29745,
                  "shallow_advance" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "build_scorer" : 30768
                },
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "type" : "DocValuesFieldExistsQuery",
                    "description" : "DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=@timestamp]",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 18317,
                    "breakdown" : {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                      "match_count" : 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                      "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                      "next_doc" : 1474,
                      "match" : 0,
                      "next_doc_count" : 1,
                      "score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score" : 0,
                      "advance" : 1541,
                      "advance_count" : 1,
                      "score" : 0,
                      "build_scorer_count" : 2,
                      "create_weight" : 1184,
                      "shallow_advance" : 0,
                      "create_weight_count" : 1,
                      "build_scorer" : 14118
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time" : 4660,
            "collector" : [
              {
                "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                "time_in_nanos" : 22374
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "[Axyv60mYQEGAREa2TwbgMQ][items-2020][0]",
        "searches" : [
          {
            "query" : [
              {
                "type" : "MatchNoDocsQuery",
                "description" : """MatchNoDocsQuery("User requested "match_none" query.")""", <-- here
                "time_in_nanos" : 4166,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                  "match_count" : 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                  "next_doc" : 0,
                  "match" : 0,
                  "next_doc_count" : 0,
                  "score_count" : 0,
                  "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                  "compute_max_score" : 0,
                  "advance" : 0,
                  "advance_count" : 0,
                  "score" : 0,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 1,
                  "create_weight" : 1791,
                  "shallow_advance" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "build_scorer" : 2375
                }
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time" : 4353,
            "collector" : [
              {
                "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                "time_in_nanos" : 12887
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations" : [ ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So there are couple of questions here:

- Does skipping truly skip shards?
- How are skipped shards and MatchNoDocsQuery different?
- What's the cost of MatchNoDocsQuery?
- How does sorting allow shards to be skipped?
- If we sort results, do we really completely skip shards and not even touch them during search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a great deal of questions bundled into one, but here's my attempt:

> Does skipping truly skip shards?
>
> How does sorting allow shards to be skipped?
>
> If we sort results, do we really completely skip shards and not even touch them during search?

Yes, ES tries to be smart enough to figure out which shards to hit before actually sending the query to those shards. The [`_search_shards` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-shards.html) helps here but not only as can be seen from the explanation in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/51852).

If you [search issues](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues) for the keywords `can_match`, `skip` and `shard` you'll find plenty of other optimizations implemented all over the place that aim at making ES execution plan smarter and faster.

If you want to see how this is coded, you can start in the [`SearchService.canMatch()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/b245348b563cc0a7c0b7b5ce600910fc94887021/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchService.java#L1185-L1194) method. That's where the service can decide whether the query can be  rewritten to `MatchNoDocsQuery`. If you add a `suggest` or `global` aggregation (which must visit all documents no matter what), you'll see that shards are not skipped any more, even with the `sort` present.

> What's the cost of MatchNoDocsQuery?

I wouldn't worry about it, as it's not only negligible, but out of your hands.

> How does sorting allow shards to be skipped?

As explained in the issue #51852 I linked above, `This change will rewrite the shard queries to match none if the bottom sort value computed in prior shards is better than all values in the shard.` In other words, ES is smart enough to know which will contain valid hits or not depending on the sort value. In your case, since the sort on the timestamp excludes all values from 2020, ES knows that the shard(s) from the 2020 index can be excluded since none will match.

Another possibility is to leverage [index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html) so that terms are sorted at indexing time. Terms are sorted in each segment of the index but also every time segments are merged, the new merged set of terms needs to be resorted again, so this can have performance implications. Test before use!

Comment: That is great. I understand it's been couple of questions here, but it would be too difficult to wrap this into one. Thank you!

Comment: Great, no worries! I'm glad if that shed some light on your questions ;-)

Comment: I know you don't need to answer this anymore. But is there a measurable cost difference between a skipped shard vs. `MatchNoDocsQuery` against that shard? I realized that was my main concern but I didn't ask it.

Comment: I think it's negligible. If it wasn't then I think something needs to be fixed in the ES core... Again, these are optimizations that are out of your hands, so I'm unsure what you could do against this, except directly targeting the 2019 index instead of the alias if you know your timestamp constraint will exclude the 2020 index anyway. In that case, there's no such optimization taking place, whether sorting is used or not